# Array List Iterator

Tags: java, arraylist

I am looking to remove the element from an array list, the user has to input the  element to be removed. At the moment my Iterator seems to be wrong. User inputs the Car Model, Color, ID Plate, Number of doors. User has to input the id and it should delete the whole element

Brand is :Nissan Color is Black ID is LS57GHT Door is 4 (this should be all deleted when user inputs the correct ID).

This is what I am using :

```
ArrayList<String> List;
List = new ArrayList<>(maxCapacity);

for (Iterator<String> iterator = List.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
     String id = input.next();
     if (List.equals(id)) {
         iterator.remove();
     }
}
```

Comment: very bad practice to name variable with capital letter as `List`.

Comment: `List` is an `ArrayList` and `id` is a `String`. What do you expect to happen with `if (List.equals(id))`? When will an `ArrayList` ever equal a `String` (hint: never).

Comment: your code is all wrong, you'll get infinite loop. You are not promoting the iterator at all (hasNext is not enough) your if will never be true since you're comparing String to List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code as in example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
    System.out.println("Input ID you want remove: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputId = scanner.nextLine();

    System.out.println("List before removing: " + list);

    for (Iterator<String> iterator = list.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        String id = iterator.next();
        if (id.equals(inputId)) {
            iterator.remove();
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("List after removing: " + list);
}
```

You'll get the following output:

```
Input ID you want remove: 
a
List before removing: [a, b, c]
List after removing: [b, c]
```

Example can be reproduced [here](http://ideone.com/KNjnNw).

And never use a capital letters to name your variables, it makes code unreadable and sometimes confusing. In your case `ArrayList` named `List` looks like `java.util.List` interface.

Comment: You are all wrong. `boolean  remove(Object o)`  [List API]{https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28int%29}

Comment: it is not `List`'s method but `Iterator`'s: `void remove()`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove()).

Comment: Why iterate an List just to remove an object if there is already methods for it.

Comment: that's different question

Comment: String enterID;
                    enterID=input.next();

                    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                        String current = iterator.next();
                        if (current.equalsIgnoreCase(enterID)) {
                            iterator.remove();
                            break;
                        }
                    }

Comment: ye when i do this

Comment: ye when i do all this i get Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Comment: can you try `CopyOnWriteArrayList`? I've updated an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125810/discussion-between-tomaszsvd-and-dimasan).

Answer (score 2):

1. You actually need to get the current element of the iterator by calling

   ```
   String current = iterator.next();
   ```

   inside your loop.
2. You are prompting the user to enter a number (assuming your `input` is actually a `Scanner` that you declared somewhere earlier) in every iteration of your loop. You should move that call out of the loop.
3. You want to compare the currently iterated element (see 1.) to the ID entered by the user. At the moment you are comparing your entire `ArrayList` object to the ID string, which will always be false.